# MahApps Progress Indicator not stretching to content

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a MahApps progress indicator declared like this:

```
<Controls:ProgressIndicator ProgressColour="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Width="600" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Self, Path=DataContext.ShowProgress, Converter={StaticResource b2v}, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
```

And for some reason the indicator bars do not stretch the size of the control. It only fills about 20% of the width. (I can't show a picture as my reputation is too low).

Has anyone experienced this before?

Cheers

**Edit**

The indicator is on a stackpanel declared like this:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Orientation="Vertical">
```

Comment: Samuel, thanks, I've already tried that but no luck. I've pretty much tried different combos of stretch, auto and columnspan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

In the latest version from nuget or [Github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) `ProgressIndicator` seems to be removed(cos it was buggy).

[Pull request that removed the control early this year](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/939)

> This release, again, contains some breaking changes. We try to break things now rather than later, when we release version 1.0 (which is hopefully soon).
>
> A quick overview:
>
> ProgressIndicator is now removed, as it wasn't working as expected. Use MetroProgressBar with IsIndeterminate = True instead, which should give a much smoother experience.

I just tried the sample with

```
<Controls:MetroProgressBar Width="300"
                            Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                            Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                            IsIndeterminate="True"
                            Maximum="100"
                            Minimum="0" />
```

[image]

Comment: Great, let me check out the update and I'll comment.

Comment: @Charlie just checked a previous version of the lib and seems as far as look goes `ProgressRing` is not the new `ProgressIndicator`. `MetroProgressBar` with `isIndeterminate="True"` gives you the same behavior and a close enough look & feel.

Comment: Viv, thanks so much! It's sorted. Your suggestion was spot-on.